# angular add slash before hash in url

Tags: angularjs

When i try to add a hash in the url like :

```
<a href="#whatever">whatever</a>
```

or

```
window.location.hash = 'whatever';
```

it appends a '/' before the hash world

```
=> www.mysite.com/#whatever
```

but it should be

```
=> www.mysite.com#whatever
```

I know this is caused by angular, but i can find a way to prevent it.
Is there a way to prevent this behaviour ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Turn on html5 mode:

```
.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

See more detail [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

Answer (score 2):

For those new to AngularJS world, configuration should be defined when declaring the module. E.g.:

```
var someModule = angular.module("someModule", [/* dependent modules come here */],
    function ($locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true
        });
});
```