# how to remove hash tag (#) from url address in ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My url looks like this 
http://127.0.0.1:50884/index.html#/home

This is index page. I am using angular ui-router to change to various views like but url comes with # tag like this: 
http://127.0.0.1:50884/index.html#/mobileOperator
http://127.0.0.1:50884/index.html#/contentExpertise

Question : 
Is there a way to remove/clean # tag from url.. to show the url path like below:

http://127.0.0.1:50884/index.html/home

http://127.0.0.1:50884/index.html/contentExpertise

I tried html5mode but it give angular error in console.

```
Error: [$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.2/$location/nobase
K/<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:6:421
pf/this.$get<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:110:96
h/<.invoke@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:41:293
gb/F<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:43:96
d@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:40:270
e@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:41:1
h/<.invoke@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:41:86
gb/F<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:43:96
d@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:40:270
e@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:41:1
h/<.invoke@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:41:86
gb/F<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:43:96
d@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:40:270
e@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:41:1
h/<.invoke@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:41:86
s/</<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:52:121
n@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:7:364
s/<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:52:90
h/<.invoke@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:41:293
e/<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:38:458
h/<.invoke@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:41:293
gb/F<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:43:96
d@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:40:270
K@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:71:447
la@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:60:266
R@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:58:229
R@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:58:397
R@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:58:397
N@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:56:263
Ac/c/</<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:21:99
sf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:140:363
sf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:141:83
Ac/c/<@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:21:57
h/<.invoke@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:41:293
Ac/c@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:20:1
Ac@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:21:274
de@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:20:83
@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/angular-v1.5.min.js:306:372
n.Callbacks/i@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2:27060
n.Callbacks/j.fireWith@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2:27828
.ready@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2:29619
J@http://127.0.0.1:50884/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2:29804
"
```

Please help

Comment: See this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388860/angular-add-slash-before-hash-in-url/28388903#28388903

Comment: use this :: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, AngularJS will route URLs with a hashtag.
It is very easy to get clean URLs and remove the hashtag from the URL using `$locationProvider` in AngularJS.
You need to inject `$locationProvider` into your config section of module and use the HTML5 History API like this. 
e.g.

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/aboutus',
            templateUrl: 'aboutus.html'   
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Also don't forget to put a `<base href="/">` tag inside index.html  section.

Comment: now my url looks like http://127.0.0.1:49625/home but after adding this if I press refresh I get message 'Cannot GET /home' even if i go back its again the same message say from other url also.

Comment: Now you need to rewrite your url .Let me know which server-side  technology you are using with angularJS

Comment: i am on local server using bracket.io. and here is the git repo  https://github.com/vipul-verma/naysa

Comment: also on raw git it not loading the views please help here's the link: https://rawgit.com/vipul-verma/naysa/master/index.html

Comment: Using this  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html).

Comment: and how to do that any reference pls

Comment: Assuming you are using Apache and your index file is index.php or index.html , try adding the following to your .htaccess file to create a rewrite rule before trying either of the other two solutions.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)       /index.php/#/$1 
</IfModule>

Comment: .net Project  Add this in Web.Config
<system.webServer> <rewrite> <rules><rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="^index\.html" ignoreCase="false" /> <action type="None" /></rule> <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="." ignoreCase="false" /> <conditions> <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" /><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
 </conditions><action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />   </rule>
 </rules> </rewrite> </system.webServer>

Answer (score 2):

In order for html5 mode to work you must define a baseurl like:

```
<base href="whatever/" />
```

See w3schools for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: it help me for your **whatever**  in our case it was `base_url()`